# Can I invoke native HTML5 input tooltip using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

In HTML5 you can use [input patterns](http://html5pattern.com/) and when the input is wrong or required yet empty you get a browser-specific tooltip over the field. I was wondering if I can play with it. For example, I can use my own custom client-side validation that can't be done using pattern.
Is there some kind of event I can trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the pattern attribute to be impossible-to-match via JS so it always 'fails', causing it to show the tooltip. Something like `a{99999999999}`

I'd be interested to know what kind of validation it is though that can't be done with a regex.

Comment: Many validations shouldn't be done with a regex. For example a regex shouldn't be validated using a regex.

Comment: Definitely. I'm just interested in what this one is.